# Partial lift for Monads?

Tags: haskell, lifting

Is there something like a partial lift for monads?
I need the type signature to be this:

```hs
Monad m => (a1 -> r) -> a1 -> m r
```

Instead of this:

```hs
Monad m => (a1 -> r) -> m a1 -> m r
```

For use with `>=>` and other reasons. I'm looking for the canonical way of doing the above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's just `(return .)`: all you need to do is inject the return value of your function into `m`, which `return` accomplishes.  Usually, this is just written inline, as `return . f` or `return $ f x`, where `f :: a -> r`; I've never seen it defined.

(Also, these days, that could be `(pure .)` instead, which has the more general type `Applicative f => (a -> r) -> a -> f r`.)

Comment: Is there a shorthand name for it? This is in another language where the above wouldn't be as succinct, but more like `f (a) => MyMonad.pure(f(a))`, and I want to add it as syntactic sugar but can't think of a name for it

Comment: @gyeh, no, not that I've ever seen. It's convenient enough in Haskell that it wouldn't be worth tying up a nice name for it.

Comment: @gyeh: To add to what dfeuer said, you can always check on [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for these things, but [`(a -> b) -> (a -> m b)`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+m+b%29), [`Applicative f => (a -> b) -> (a -> f b)`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Applicative+f+%3D%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+f+b%29), and [`Monad m => (a -> b) -> (a -> m b)`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+m+b%29) don't turn up anything relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Anoher way of building this function is using a [Kleisli arrow](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html):

```
ghci> import Control.Arrow
ghci> :t runKleisli . arr
runKleisli . arr :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> a -> m b
```

Comment: Hmm… since gyeh is looking for a name for this function, `kleisli` wouldn't actually be the worst option.

Comment: @Antal Spector-Zabusky Yeah `kliesli` sounds like an appropriate name for it :). Thanks for finding that @danidiaz.